# Cognos 11.2 data module - custom SQL table from an existing custom SQL table

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have a datamodule with some tables in it via a database connection. I created a custom SQL table "customSQLt1" querying one of the existing tables, all works as usual.
Now i want to create another custom SQL table "customSQLt2, but this time I want to query the custom SQL table i created earlier - "customSQLt1", not the existing tables.

When i go to New->Custom SQL table and write

select * from customSQLt1

it gives me an expression error. Is what i want even possible in Cognos 11.2?

Thank you for any hints

Comment: Please use valid Cognos terminology.  "database connection" is not a valid term.  Do you mean a data server?  Where is the "New" button in the data module editor?  Do you mean the "Add sources and tables" button, or something else?  Please use the terminology from the user interface.  The term you seek may be on a tooltip.  Also, describe the entire process with enough detail for someone else to follow.  Maybe I'm opening the editor in a different way from you so I'm lost before step one.  And reproduce the problem using the samples data if you can.

Comment: What does the error message say? It's generally a good idea to include that.  Reading the error message can help you understand what is being complained about. Why are you trying to do what you state you are trying? Why do you think you need to have these sql tables, especially those of a simple select statement type.  Do not restrict yourself to just the immediate situation but describe the general pattern of the model you are trying to build.  Contemplate the possibility that the pattern you seem to be employing does not seem to follow Cognos best practices. Sorry I was on holiday till now.